# Cannot override woocommerce variable.php template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, overriding, shopping-cart

I want to customize the *add to cart form* section on my single product page by overriding and modifying my variable.php template page.  I've added a duplicate to my woocommerce folder for my theme and began to alter it but I do not see the changes to the form.  I have been successful with overriding other templates such as my single-product.php.  I have added an image of my file set up for my template and what I am trying to change.

**This is my file setup with the file I am using to override**

[image: This is my file setup with the file I am using to override]

**This is the area I am trying to modify**

[image: This is the area I am trying to modify]

Answer (score 0):

The file you need to overwrite is found at:

```
your-theme\woocommerce\single-product\add-to-cart\variable.php
```

Comment: Are you saying I need to create that exact directory to edit the file.  I added woocommerce manually so my woocommerce folder only has what I add to it.

Comment: Yes that's correct you need to keep exactly the same file structure. [template files](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)